# Show/Hide Function(s)

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show, show-hide

Fixed Solution

```
    //Hide and Show Divs
function hideContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function showInlineContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "inline";
}
function showBlockContent(d) {
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}
function reverseDisplay(d) {
    if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
    else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
    //Hide and Show Divs

    // Show Div <a href="javascript:showInlineContent('crafting2')">Click to show.</a>
function researchStick() {
    if (stick >= 1 && research1Progress < 100) {            // Want to be able to show progress
    stick = stick - 1;                                      // each time you click me I want to use 1 stick
    research1Progress = research1Progress + 5;              // each stick brings research progress up 5
    document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;     // Show the player the update
}
    if (research1Progress == 100) {                         // When reaches 100
        showInlineContent('crafting2');                         // show crafting2
}
    // when research hits 100 unlocks blunt object for crafting
    // this clickable button should hide after completion
    // add achievement for first research project
```

}

Here is the fixed solution after applying some fixes. being able to call more then one if function is helpful to know, especially since all the tutorials I took did not specifically indicate it otherwise. maybe is was meant to be obvious but knowing this has helped me a newcomer to java create more code on my own

Comment: You never call `researchComplete`. Is it called from an `onclick` handler somewhere?

Comment: Declare `research1Progress = 0` upon initializing your code. It think it's returning `NaN` now.

Comment: You don't declare research1Progress anywhere in this code, so that may result in an error when you try to use it/read it. Also, you didn't add curly braces after the `if` statement in the `researchStick` function, and due to the lack of indentation, it's impossible to tell whether this intentional or not.

Comment: @Barmar ah your correct I was too focused on something else. I was trying to get the researchComplete function to happen as soon as reasearch1Progress hit 100. so would I just call the complete function in my researchstick function?

Comment: That's probably right. Or it's so simply you could just copy the code into `researchStick`

Comment: @Barmar I'm new to most all of this so this may be a weird question but... can I have multiple if statements in one function? or would I have to use the else/else if.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple if statements. You can mix and match anything, programming is very logical like that. It just executes each statement, one by one.

Comment: @GolezTrol I did forget to add that. Thank you. I'm still very new to coding. *not intentional*

Comment: That might be part of the issue then. Without them, `research1Progress` is incremented by 5 each time researchStick is called, regardless of the condition. You really should apply indentation to your code. It helps tremendously when you need to read back your code when you want to make changes or find a bug. Also, try to press F12 in your browser. You will probably get developer tools, including a console that shows JavaScript errors. Very valuable to learn the various possibilities of this feature.